# Sorting a C array based on contents of another array

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array `A` whose elements are indexes. The indexes refer to another array `B` whose value will determine the order of `A`. So, I would like to sort `A` such that `B[ A[i] ]` is increasing.

For example:

```
A = [0, 1, 4, 5, 7]
B = [5, 3, 8, 2, 2, 7, 1, 6, 3, 9]
```

Sorted `A` would be

```
A' = [ 7, 4, 1, 0, 5 ]
```

Is this possible with C's built-in sort, or am I going to have to write my own implementation?

EDIT: These arrays are local function variables.

Comment: There would be ugly hacks that can get this to work with qsort, but I think you are better off writing your own version..

Comment: @Pavan I'd prefer fighting zombies in the desert rather than using my own sorting procedure in production.

Comment: It's  not an ugly hack. It's merely that there's a function that maps the array value to the sort order. In this case, the function can be immplemented by an array lookup, but it's hardly an unusual requirement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use `qsort`, the best thing to-do would be to re-wrap the indexes in A and the values in B into a struct, and then make a comparator based on a new array that struct.  For instance:

```
typedef struct
{
    int index_from_A;
    int value_from_B;
} index_value_wrapper;

index_value_wrapper index_wrapper_array[5];

for (int i=0; i < 5; i++)
{
    index_wrapper_array[i].index_from_A = A[i];
    index_wrapper_array[i].value_from_B = B[A[i]];
}

int comparitor (const void* lhs, const void* rhs)
{
    return (lhs.value_from_B - rhs.value_from_B);
}
```

Now you can run `qsort` on the struct array and from there you can extract the proper sorted sequence you desired for the original array `A` without having to use a custom sorting function.

Answer (score 4):

If you have it available, [qsort_r](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/qsort_r/) provides a way to do this.  You can give it context information in an additional parameter.  That context is passed to the comparison function.  You can access that additional information to extract the desired sorting information.

The Microsoft compiler has a similar one:  [qsort_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4xc60xas.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use `qsort` and a custom comparator

```
int comparator(const void *x, const void *y)
{
    return ( b[*(int*)x] - b[*(int*)y] );
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to pass the array references to the comparator?

Comment: @ajwood I am unsure I understand your question

Comment: Ajwood, If you mean the array indices, no - the array elements move around as the sort progresses

Comment: @cnicutar: Your answer would be perfect... _but_ these arrays are local variables in a function, so the comparator can't check values of `B`

Comment: @ajwood: From what I can see, in the code snipped above, `b` would have to be some type of globally accessible array.

Comment: @ajwood you can use nested function if your compiler supports them. [GCC does](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html).

Comment: @Banthar: Woah! I had no idea that was legit!

Answer (score 1):

Use your rule as the comparison function to qsort (as long as B is longer than A):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int A[] = {0, 1, 4, 5, 7};
int B[]= {5, 3, 8, 2, 2, 7, 1, 6, 3, 9};

 int my_cmp(const void *a_, const void *b_,void *arg_)
 {
   const int *a = a_, *b = b_;

   if(B[*a] == B[*b])
       return 0;
    else if (B[*a] < B[*b])
        return -1;
    else
        return 1;

}

int main(int argc,char *arga[])
{
    int i;

    qsort(A,sizeof A/sizeof A[0] ,sizeof A[0],my_cmp);

    puts("Sorted A");
    for(i = 0 ; i < sizeof A/sizeof A[0]; i++) {
        printf("A[%d] : %d B[A[%d]] : %d\n",i,A[i],i,B[A[i]]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This gives:

```
$ ./a.out
Sorted A
A[0] : 4 B[A[0]] : 2
A[1] : 1 B[A[1]] : 3
A[2] : 0 B[A[2]] : 5
A[3] : 7 B[A[3]] : 6
A[4] : 5 B[A[4]] : 7
```

Available on many platforms is also qsort_r(on linux you'll have to `#define _GNU_SOURCE` before including `<stdlib.h>` to use it. Using that, you'd change the comparison function to e.g.

```
int my_cmp(const void *a_, const void *b_,void *arg_)
 {
    const int *a = a_, *b = b_, *arg = arg_;

   if(arg[*a] == arg[*b])
       return 0;
    else if (arg[*a] < arg[*b])
        return -1;
    else
        return 1;

}
```

And call qsort_r like

```
qsort_r(A,sizeof A/sizeof A[0] ,sizeof A[0],my_cmp,B);
```

Comment: This works well as long as it is not multi-threaded.  If it is not single-threaded and the reference data (B) is not static, then it would not work.

Comment: @Paul qsort is the only standard sorting function in C and it works like that, otherwise you'll have to roll your own , or use something non-standard, like qsort_r - added an example for that. Unless you're in a multithreaded environment, A and B can very well be local. You just need to set a global `int *` to your B array before calling qsort

Comment: @nos, standard or not if it doesn't work you can't use it :) A global works (although it's a bit of a code smell) or use a wrapper struct as others (including me) have suggested.

Comment: @Nos, yes, it does. But it wasn't part of your answer or comment when I added my comment... qsort_r is definitely the way to go if it's available

Answer (score 1):

Create another array C of type `struct { int a_value; int b_value}`, initialise each element to the values of each index of a and the value looked up from b. Sort that, traverse the sorted C copying the a_values back into A.

Viola. No, that's a large violin. Voila!